Can women travel alone domestically?
I know that it is haram for women to travel alone internationally but can a woman travel within their own country or region or municipality (domestic)?
Because if a woman want to becoma a train driver she has to drive through a region or within the same country but come home the same day.

YES A WOMAN CAN TRAVEL WITH HER COUNTRY BUT FOR INTERNATIONALLY TRAVELING IT DEPENDS WHAT MAKE HER TO TRAVEL TO DO SO.

Whether the travel is international or domestic does not make a difference. In exceptional cases it is permitted for a woman to even travel alone internationally, such as when migrating from Dar al-Harb to Dar al-Islam.
However in general it is forbidden for a woman to travel alone, regardless of whether the travel is international or domestic. Consider the hadith:

قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏لا تسافر المرأة إلا مع ذي محرم، ولا يدخل عليها رجل إلا ومعها محرم.‏ فقال رجل يا رسول الله إني أريد أن أخرج في جيش كذا وكذا، وامرأتي تريد الحج‏.‏ فقال ‏اخرج معها
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "A woman should not travel except with a Dhu-Mahram and no man may visit her except in the presence of a Dhu-Mahram."
A man got up and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I intend to go to such and such an army and my wife wants to perform Hajj."
The Prophet (ﷺ) said (to him), "Go along with her (to Hajj)."
— Bukhari

The hadith says that women can not travel without a mahram, and it does not mention any distinction between domestic and international travel. Hence it can be deduced that this distinction has no effect on the ruling.
Further, the hadith is on domestic travel. Hajj was only performed by the Muslims after the conquest of Makkah when it had become part of the Islamic territory.
Some ahadith do put a condition on the length of the journey as such scholars hold the following stances on this matter:

Some hold that a woman can not travel alone if it qualifies as a journey according to Islam the threshold of which is the same distance where prayers can be shortened. This is held by the Hanafis. It is based on the hadith:

لا تسافر المرأة ثلاثة أيام إلا مع ذي محرم
A woman should not travel for more than three days except with a Mahram
— Bukhari


Others hold that it applies to every travel which is considered a journey by custom. The reason is that there are different ahadith which mention different distances such as Bukhari 1086,  Bukhari 1088,  Bukhari 1197. They say that the distance mentioned in the ahadith is according to the situation of the questioner and does not make a difference in the ruling - all travel by a woman is forbidden unless she is accompanied by a mahram or her husband.



I was asking because i want to become a train driver and a train driver that drives through a region or within the country but comes home the same day as a normal work day.
